# Unable to get path for video in Android

Tags: android, uri

I have a URI like so: `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video%3A818`. I'm trying to get the path so that I can upload to my server with the below method:

```
private String getRealPathFromURIVideo(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String result = cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

I also tried the below:

```
private String getFilePathFromContentUri(Uri selectedVideoUri) {
    String filePath;
    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA};

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedVideoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    return filePath;
}
```

I keep getting null from that method! I need the `File` object after getting the path. Why is that method giving me the null value? Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do it like so:

```
private String getRealPathFromURIForVideo(Uri selectedVideoUri) {
    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(selectedVideoUri);
    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

    String[] column = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
    String sel = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID + "=?";
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, column, sel, new String[]{ id }, null);
    String filePath = "";

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return filePath;
}
```